# Python attribute error after result is outputed

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program reads a file line-by-line and uses reg-ex at every line.
The program executes well for all lines, but throws the following at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    output = pattern.search(line).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

My code is the following:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\|)')

# open input file
input_file = open('input.fas', 'r')

while True:
    line = input_file.readline()
    if line == '' or line is None:
        print('EOF')
        break
    else:
        output = pattern.search(line).group()
        print(output)
```

Comment: You can try printing `pattern.search(line)` which error says in `None`. And calling `group` function to  `None` gave the error.

Comment: Yes, what is confusing me is how does the last read line skips the if statement.

Comment: Every non-empty line will run the search. If the search does not match anything you'll be calling `None.group()`

Answer (score 1):

According to [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), `search`  returns None if no position in the string matches the pattern.
So, may be you need to check if pattern search returned something before calling `group`. May be you can try your 
`else` as following:

```
else:
    pattern_match = pattern.search(line)
    # check for search first before calling group
    if pattern_match:
        output = pattern_match.group()
        print(output)
```

May be something like below for above code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\>)(.*?)(?=\|)')

# open input file
input_file = open('input.fas', 'r')

while True:
    line = input_file.readline()
    if line == '' or line is None:
        print('EOF')
        break
    else:
        pattern_match = pattern.search(line)
        # check for search first before calling group
        if pattern_match:
            output = pattern_match.group()
            print(output)
```